# vscode git, sftp configure

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, sftp

vscode is using git and sftp.

The problem is that I can't upload the contents of git pull directly to the server.

Is there any way to detect changes in the file when git pull and upload them to the server automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I find that sftp option

```
"uploadOnSave": true,
"syncMode": "full",
"watcher": {
    "files": "**",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "autoDelete": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Wiki page for config commands](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/wiki/Common-Config#watcherfiles) on the [Github repository](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp), you should

> Set `uploadOnSave` to false when you watch everything.

Please go have a look at the wiki.

According to your answer, you are watching everything, so it is a good idea to set `uploadOnSave` to `false`.

Also, in one of the [comments for an issue](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/294#issuecomment-429240469), the creator of repository wrote this, which might be useful in your case.

```
{
  "uploadOnSave": false,
  "watcher": {
    "files": "**/*",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "autoDelete": true
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below... It worked very well for me

```
"watcher": {
    "files": "**/*.{css,css.map}",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    "autoDelete": false
},
```